# Pull in field from an unrelated object into a report based off text

Tags: reporting

I have a report where each row is the total count of records that have the same text in a field. In this case, that field is a name and the record count is the number of records where that name occurred.

| Name | Record Count |
| --- | --- |
| John Johnson | 1 |
| Anne Johnson | 3 |
| Mage Johnson | 9 |
| Matt Johnson | 3 |
| Barb Johnson | 11 |

Each of these names actually have contact records in our system so I want to have their email as part of the report, but since it's just a text field on the object I'm running the report on, I can't figure out how to get that email. Since the name is just a text field on this report, it's not a related object. Basically I want to retrieve the email of the person and add that as a column like this:

| Name | Record Count | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Johnson | 1 | jj@email.com |
| Anne Johnson | 3 | aj@email.com |
| Mage Johnson | 9 | mj@email.com |
| Matt Johnson | 3 | mj@email.com |
| Barb Johnson | 11 | jb@email.com |

Comment: You'll need to relate it to the Contact or (as part of whatever solution you've got in place) add email as a field to your other object.  There's no magic.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to define a relationship when creating reports in Salesforce. The relationship needs to be defined before the report is created.

What you can do is create a Lookup(Contact) field on the first object and then use Flow or Apex Trigger to populate the lookup field when it is created or updated.

If you have multiple records in the FirstObject that would need to be updated you can run the following in Developer Tools to execute a change in the records:

```
update [SELECT Id FROM FirstObject__c WHERE Contact__c = NULL];
```